# JPA Version column isn't updating after merge()

Tags: jpa, version

I'm updating an entity via `EntityManager#merge()` but the new JPA version number from JPA isn't being reflected correctly in the returned entity.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class LeadService {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "joose")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Lead createOrUpdateLead(Lead lead) {
        if (lead.getId() != null) {
            em.merge(lead);
        } else {
            em.persist(lead);
        }
        return lead;
    }
```

How should I deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: In the `createLeadOrUpdateLead` method, if you log the version of `lead` before and after the operation, does `lead` change? If not, maybe you can just use `em.refresh(lead)` to get the latest from the DB.

Comment: Do'h. Actually I just found the bug. `em.merge(lead)` should be `lead = em.merge(lead);`

Comment: Ah, classic mistake.

Comment: Do you mind removing your question as you posted the obvious answer for yourself? As an alternative, you could post your solution and accept it as an answer then... As @DavidS pointed out, this is a "classic" mistake and most probably has been answered 100+ times on StOf already.

Comment: No, I think it's valuable for someone googling